# How to dockerize multi-file python project

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, fastapi

My project structure:

```
├── async_fastapi
    ├── main.py
    ├── auth.py
    ├── db.py
    ├── schemas.py
    ├── Token.py
    ├── users.py
    ├── items.py
```

This question might seem dumb for you but I can not figure it out. It is my believe that Dockerfile should be build on specific python file. But what if my project is spread across multiple files/directories ? Do I have create specific Dockerfile for each .py and then put them together with docker-compose or is there other way ?

Comment: You mean to say, each of the python files has to be executed separately ? Or there is a single point of entry and remaining are dependencies ?. AFAIU, you have a main.py to entry point, then a single dockerfile is enough.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I wished t hear.

Answer (score 1):

Let's modify your project structure a little, so that it becomes build-easy.

```
├── requirements.txt
├── Dockerfile
├── async_fastapi
    ├── main.py
    ├── auth.py
    ├── db.py
    ├── schemas.py
    ├── Token.py
    ├── users.py
    ├── items.py
```

Put all your dependencies in the `requirements.txt` so that it can be installed in the container. In the `Dockerfile`, you can have something like below.

```
FROM python:3.8.10
ENV WORKSPACE /opt/installs
RUN mkdir -p $WORKSPACE
WORKDIR $WORKSPACE
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python3.8 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY async_fastapi .
CMD ["python3.8", "main.py"]
```

This must be enough to build it. Ofc, the docker definition is only on assumptions, which you could adjust.